# Disable rails_best_practices RestrictAutoGeneratedRoutes for devise scope routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

To limit devise auto generated routes, I have this in my route file...

```rb
  ## config/routes.rb  

  # Restrict auto generated devise routes
  devise_scope :user do
    resource :users,
             only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update],
             controller: 'users/registrations',
             path_names: { new: 'sign_up' },
             as: :user_registration
  end
```

Controller:

```rb
## app/controllers/users/registrations_controller

module Users
  # Copied by `devise` generator so we could override things.
  class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    
    def new
     # some logic
    end

    def create
     # some logic
    end

    # # Overriding and call to `super` for these two method removes unused routes warning, I don't want this
    # # rubocop:disable Lint/UselessMethodDefinition
    # def edit
    #   super
    # end

    # def update
    #   super
    # end
    # # rubocop:enable Lint/UselessMethodDefinition
```

`rails_best_practices` linter is giving warning `restrict auto-generated routes users (only: [:new, :create])` if I don't override the `edit & update` methods in `RegistrationsController`.

Is there a way to disable `RestrictAutoGeneratedRoutesCheck` for those routes?
Or what would be the most feasible way to resolve this warning? Thank you.

Comment: I don't see why you would do this in the first place as `devise_for` lets you customize the generated routes without the wheel reinventing...

Comment: Can we limit routes using devise for ?

Answer (score 0):

What about a custom `rails_best_practices.yml` with a tweaked `RestrictAutoGeneratedRoutesCheck` entry? See: https://github.com/flyerhzm/rails_best_practices

Comment: Is there a way to disable the check for a specific block like robocop? I didn't find any except disabling the check for the whole routes file.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `rails_best_practices.yml` and you can apply the ignored_files option on any rule by giving a regexp or array of regexp describing the path of the files you don't want to be:

In your case `RestrictAutoGeneratedRoutesCheck{ignored_files: 'routes.rb'}`.